# AJAX on dynamic class value for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

**Short version:**

If I have

```
.favorite-link
  = link_to some_path, class: (@condition ? "favorited" : "") do 
    .star-image
```

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :hacks do
    post "favorite", on: :member    
  end
```

**hacks_controller.rb**

```
  def favorite
    @favorite = Favorite.find_or_initialize_by(user_id: current_user.id, hack_id: params[:id])
    if @favorite.persisted?
      @favorite.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js 
      end
    else
      @favorite.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js 
      end
    end
  end
```

**favorite.js.coffee**

```
$('.favorite-link a').toggleClass("favorited")
```

This last bit of code changes EVERY instance. How do I toggle just the one I clicked? Doing `.on 'click', ->   $(this).toggleClass("favorited") does weird stuff, like change it only every other time I click it. Plus, the render js is not suited for that way.

Or perhaps a better way to accomplish toggling the class value is: how do I toggle the star using ajax (i.e. make the page evaluate `@condition` again after clicking the link?)

---

Irrelevant to the core of the question, but FYI:

**SCSS**

```
.favorite-link {
  a.favorited {
    .star-image {
      background-image: url('star-on.png');
  }   
}

.favorite-link {
  a {
    .star-image {
      background-image: url('star-off.png');
    }
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery to add the class as part of your Ajax response handler:

```
$(".star-image").addClass("favorited");
```

There is also `.toggleClass` and `.removeClass` to fill out your implementation.

Comment: It's the ajax response handler portion that I'm confused about. Can you give me an example? Much thanks.

Should I use js? If so, How do I render a partial, and how do I pass variables into it?

Or should I use json? If so, what do I put in the asset js file?

This is the stuff that's confusing me.

Comment: Also, I have more than one of these, so this would target all of them.

Comment: I'm so frustrated at the internet and rails guides for not having a functional, comprehensive enough ajax guide. Where do people learn to do this stuff anyway?